# Stuck in loop that should stop after end of file - C

Tags: c, structure, scanf

I can't seem to figure out how to fix my loop in main, so that it stops at the end of file. I thought that by returning a value from my scanning functions, it would cause the loop to stop at the end of file. It seems that the variable result is not being returned.

There may be another way of looping the two function calls so they stop at end of file?

There is a commented out section that does read till end of file, but I am trying to accomplish this using the print and scan functions that have been created.

Code so far....

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define STRSIZE 20

/* Structure definitions   */
typedef struct {
        int     month,
                day,
                year;
} date_t;

typedef struct {
        double  capacity,
                current;
} tank_t;

typedef struct {
        char    make[STRSIZE],
                model[STRSIZE];
        int     odometer;
        date_t  manuf,
                purch;
        tank_t  tank;
} auto_t;

/* Function prototypes   */



int scan_date(date_t *date, FILE *inp);
int scan_tank(tank_t *tank, FILE *inp); 
int scan_auto(auto_t *vehicle, FILE *inp); 


void print_date(date_t date); 
void print_tank(tank_t tank);
void print_auto(auto_t vehicle); 

int main()
{
    auto_t      vehicle;
    date_t      date;
    tank_t      tank;
    int         i=0,
                result=1;

    FILE *inp = fopen("autos.txt","r");                /* defining file input    */

    /* Check to make sure input file is found and readable.  */
    if(inp==NULL){
        printf("Error: Input file - autos.txt - not found!\n");

        getch();
        return 0;
    }

    printf("Vehicle   Vehicle  Odometer  Date        Date          Tank       Current\n");
    printf("Make      Model    Reading   Purchased   Manufactured  Capacity   Fuel Level\n");
    printf("\n----------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");


 /*******************COMMENTED OUT*************************************
    while(status>0){
         status=fscanf(inp, "%s%s%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%lf%lf", vehicle.make,
                                                        vehicle.model,
                                                        &vehicle.odometer,
                                                        &vehicle.manuf.month,
                                                        &vehicle.manuf.day,
                                                        &vehicle.manuf.year,
                                                        &vehicle.purch.month,
                                                        &vehicle.purch.day,
                                                        &vehicle.purch.year,
                                                        &vehicle.tank.capacity,
                                                        &vehicle.tank.current);

    if(status==11){
         printf("%-10s%-9s%-10d%2d/%d/%-6d%2d/%d/%-8d%-11.1lf%.1lf\n", vehicle.make,
                                                                    vehicle.model,
                                                                    vehicle.odometer,
                                                                    vehicle.manuf.month,
                                                                    vehicle.manuf.day,
                                                                    vehicle.manuf.year,
                                                                    vehicle.purch.month,
                                                                    vehicle.purch.day,
                                                                    vehicle.purch.year,
                                                                    vehicle.tank.capacity,
                                                                    vehicle.tank.current);
         i++;}

     else if(status <11 && status>0){
         printf("\nInvalid Input - The next line of data is corrupt.\n");
     }                                              
     }                                                  
******************************************************************************/ 


   while(result>0){

        scan_auto(&vehicle, inp);

        if(result==11){

            print_auto(vehicle);
        }

        else if(result <11 && result>0){

            printf("\nInvalid Input - The next line of data is corrupt.\n");
        }                                              
     }  

    getch();
    return 0;
}

/*********************************************************************************/   
int scan_date(date_t *date, FILE *inp)
{
    int result = fscanf(
        inp,
        "%d%d%d",
        &(date->day),
        &(date->month),
        &(date->year));

    return (result == 3);
}

/*********************************************************************************/
int scan_tank(tank_t *tank, FILE *inp)
{
    int result = fscanf(
        inp,
        "%lf%lf",
        &(tank->capacity),
        &(tank->current));


    return (result == 2);

}

/*********************************************************************************/
int scan_auto(auto_t *vehicle, FILE *inp)
{
    int result = fscanf(
        inp,
        "%s%s%d",
        vehicle->make,
        vehicle->model,
        &(vehicle->odometer));

    result += scan_date(&(vehicle->purch), inp);
    result += scan_date(&(vehicle->manuf), inp);
    result += scan_tank(&(vehicle->tank), inp);

    return (result = 11);
}
/*********************************************************************************/
void print_auto(auto_t vehicle)
{
    printf("\n%-10s%-9s%-10d", vehicle.make,
                             vehicle.model,
                             vehicle.odometer);
    print_date(vehicle.purch); 
    print_date(vehicle.manuf);
    print_tank(vehicle.tank);



} 

/*********************************************************************************/

void print_date(date_t date)
{
     printf("%1d/%d/%-7d", date.day,
                           date.month,
                           date.year);

}     

/*********************************************************************************/

void print_tank(tank_t tank)
{
        printf("  %-11.1lf%.1lf", tank.capacity, 
                                tank.current);

}
```

Here is the autos.txt file it uses....

```
Mercury     Sable   99842   1   18  2001    5   30  1991    16  12.5
Mazda       Navajo  123961  2   20  1993    6   15  1993    19.3    16.7
Ford
```

I left an extra name in there, as to trigger an error message for the user to check the file to make sure its complete.

Comment: In `main()`, `result` is initialized to `1` - and **never** changes.

Answer (score 1):

Your *immediate* problem is very simple:

```
int result = 1;
while(result>0){
    scan_auto(&vehicle, inp);
    if(result==11){
        print_auto(vehicle);
    }
    else if(result <11 && result>0){
        printf("\nInvalid Input - The next line of data is corrupt.\n");
    }                                              
}
```

There is no assignment to `result` within the loop, so the loop never terminates.  You should be seeing the "Invalid Input" `printf` trigger endlessly.

And now a piece of advice: Parsing text input in C is, as a general rule, *not* best done with `fscanf`, for a whole plethora of reasons - my usual recommendation for this kind of text file is

- `getline` if available, else `fgets`, to read entire lines at once
- `strtok` to split each line into fields
- `strtol`, `strtod`, etc to convert decimal numbers to machine integers and floats.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't using the return value of `scan_auto`. You probably want:

```
result = scan_auto(&vehicle, int);
```

Also, each of your `scan_` functions should return the number of fields that were found.  Instead of things like `return (result == 3);` just `return result`.

Comment: I think it's meant as a self test. `return (result == 3);` returns 1 or 0 depending on if the correct amount is read. He simply needs to test for true or false on each function call return, and change `return (result = 11);` to `return (result == 11);`

Comment: Maybe -- the code is really confused, of course.  Since `scan_auto` adds up the return values of `scan_date` and `scan_tank`, and the main loop was trying to check the total value, it looked like he was trying to count the number of fields that were read.

Comment: I was trying to count the fields that were read, but I see that is not working. Im trying to find a way to loop it without not using fscanf.